# Mapping nullable and non nullable double using a ValueTransformer

Tags: automapper

I have a class with `double` and `double?` and I want to round these values in the mapping process.

I created a small code sample to illustrate the problem that I am facing:

When I use `AddTransform<double?>` the transformation works for `double?` but does nothing for `double`.
When I add `AddTransform<double>` the transformation works as long as all nullable fields have a value.
When both transformers are added and at least one field is null I see following error:

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException

Inner Exception 1:
InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.


Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
TestSource -> TestDestination
AutoMapperValueTransformer.TestSource -> AutoMapperValueTransformer.TestDestination

Type Map configuration:
TestSource -> TestDestination
AutoMapperValueTransformer.TestSource -> AutoMapperValueTransformer.TestDestination

Destination Member:
Prop3
```

Here the code to reproduce the issue

```
using System;

using AutoMapper;

namespace AutoMapperValueTransformer
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => 
                cfg.CreateMap<TestSource, TestDestination>()
                    .AddTransform<double?>(t => t.HasValue ? Math.Round(t.Value, 3) : t)
                    //.AddTransform<double>(t => Math.Round(t, 3))
                    );
            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

            var src = new TestSource()
            {
                Prop1 = 3.3454353,
                Prop2 = 3.3454353,
                Prop3 = null,
            };

            var dst = mapper.Map<TestSource, TestDestination>(src);

            Console.WriteLine(dst.Prop1);
            Console.WriteLine(dst.Prop2);
            Console.WriteLine(dst.Prop3);
        }
    }

    internal class TestSource
    {
        public double Prop1 { get; set; }

        public double? Prop2 { get; set; }

        public double? Prop3 { get; set; }
    }

    internal class TestDestination
    {
        public double Prop1 { get; set; }

        public double? Prop2 { get; set; }

        public double? Prop3 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
cfg.CreateMap<double, double>().ConvertUsing(source => Math.Round(source, 3));
```

Or try the [MyGet](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/The-MyGet-build.html) build.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it influences the behavior of all double mappings. I also tried to create and add two distinct profiles but the mapping was still influenced by the double map. Using the transformation the other mappings are not influenced.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea :) Then try a value converter or use the MyGet build.